# How to handle email notifications in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design

My app has several events based on which a user gets an email notification. What's the best way to handle this from a software/database design perspective?

Here are two instances when I send out an email to a user:

1. Someone replies to their comment.
2. Someone likes their comment.

I also need a way for the user to turn these email events off individually in their user settings.

Here is what I'm thinking of doing (which doesn't feel like a good way):

- Have a bunch of boolean fields in the user table that turn on or off each email notification (eg: is_send_email_replies, is_send_comment_likes).
- The user can then turn these bool values on or off in their setting.

Is there a better more pragmatic way to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

This is considered a typical user settings where you can save it as a [Rails json field](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json) or use gems like [rails-settings](https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings)

So assuming you'll use rails-settings gem you can do it as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_settings :email_notifications
end
```

then you can set and get settings like this

```
user.settings(:email_notifications).comments = true
user.settings(:email_notifications).likes = false
user.settings(:email_notifications).comments
# => true
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you watch Ryan Bates' Railscasts on activity (ep. #406) and then reading into the [public-activity](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity) gem. That can be an elegant way to handle the events that send out notifications to users.

As for how you will store and deal with preferences, check out the [Preferences gem](https://github.com/pluginaweek/preferences) As the description itself says: `...sometimes it's necessary if you want users to be able to disable things like e-mail notifications.`

Answer (score 0):

One way that I've handled this in the past is to have a separate model for the preferences and for the email type. The preferences table acts as sort of a many to many relationship between users and types where they can set there own preference.

The main advantage here is you can add as many email types as you want (over time) and you wont be clogging up your user model.